# Excel Macro / VBA - How do I delete an entire row if a cell in one column is blank?

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I want a macro code that (1) starts at Row 3, (2) and deletes any row where its cell in Column B is blank. I've tried...

```
Sub DelBlankRows()  
    Columns("B:B").Select  
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select  
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete  
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub delrows()  
     Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to define the worksheet as well:

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Will delete every row where column B is empty.

If you need to start at row 3 until the last row:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lr As Double
    lr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: The first one only deleted the first two rows... The second one said no cells were found...

Comment: I figured out the issue. It works when I manually "Clear Contents" for all the "blank" rows... So apparently those cells that appear blank are not actually considered blank by the code. Can you help with this please?

Comment: You will need to know what the values are if not blanks. The you'll end up with a loop or something to check for those values. XlCellTypeBlanks is not going to help you in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you are going to be looping this in something... 
The concise answers given to you will not "update" the row index of your loop. I present a cleaner looking option that will likely fit into whatever you are doing:

**pseudo CODE**

```
For row = start To rowcount
    If cells(row,column).Value = "" Then
        Cells(row,column).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        row = row-1  'this is because the xlUp shift changes index for all rows BELOW your loop
    End If
Next row
```

Comment: You can always loop backwards `For row = rowcount to start Step -1` then you would not need the `row = row-1`